# Debugger-ui in another computer

Tags: node.js, react-native

Let's make this question real simple.

I've two computers, let's say `A` and `B`,connected to same network.

**Current Scenario**

I am doing my `react-native` development in `A` with an android emulator within itself . Using `Remote Debugging` feature of `react-native`, I can access the logs via `http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/`.

**What I want**

I need access `debugger-ui/` from computer `B` to get logs generated from computer `A`

**What I tried**

I collected the local IP address of computer `A`, and accessed the `debugger-ui` using it. It worked, but in console am getting below error

[image: Computer B Screenshot]

I know it happened because the computer `B` tried to access the resource from `A` using `localhost` instead the `IP` of computer `A`.

**What I want to Know?**

1) Is it possible to tell the computer `B` to access the resource from computer `A` ? If yes, how ?

2) Is there alternative solution for my problem ?

Comment: When you open the dev menu in your Android emulator (the one where you see the reload option) there should be an option called dev settings where you can change the IP of your debugger.

Comment: I tried changing the IP. It doesn't work.Should i do anything additional to that?

Comment: Ok so react native has a hardcoded URL for debugger in the most recent version...it's possible in your case that's hardcoded to localhost. What version of react native are you using?

Comment: I am using 0.56 @NemiShah